# Is it possible to disable frame-limiting in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, frame-rate

More specifically, a desktop libGDX-LWJGL application. There are configurations options to disable CPU syncing as well as vsynching, but regardless the application runs at 60fps.

This is fine for all practical uses - but out of curiousity if nothing else, I'd like to see how high the framerate could go.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Rode Hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099260/1725096)'s answer is no longer correct due to changes in the library. Try this:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.vSyncEnabled = false; // Setting to false disables vertical sync
config.foregroundFPS = 0; // Setting to 0 disables foreground fps throttling
config.backgroundFPS = 0; // Setting to 0 disables background fps throttling
```

Also, make sure any hardware vsync is off on your GPU, if possible, as @RodHyde mentioned.

Comment: 400 fps , but now box2d is way too fast

Comment: @Paul I'd ask about that on #libgdx (irc.freenode.net) or the [libGDX forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/).

Answer (score 7):

The answer depends very much on the speed of your CPU and graphics card, but if you try a configuration like the following when you create your application, and disable vsync on your graphics card, then that should push it pretty hard.

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.title = "Framerate test";
cfg.width = 1280;
cfg.height = 720;
cfg.fullscreen = false;  
cfg.useGL20 = false;
cfg.useCPUSynch = false;
cfg.forceExit = true;  
cfg.vSyncEnabled = false;
```

Disabling vsync will be somewhere in the settings for your graphics card. On my nVidia card, it is given as "Vertical sync" in the options. It was set to "Adaptive", capping the frame rate at 60fps, but after setting it to "Off", I saw > 4000fps as measured by [fraps](http://www.fraps.com/).

Answer (score 3):

`cfg.useCPUSynch` has been taken out it seems. Setting `cfg.foregroundFPS` to some large number instead did the trick for me.

Comment: This should really be a comment to @RodHyde's answer. It is technically incorrect because the OP wishes to disable frame-limiting completely. It is also incomplete as you don't mention vSyncEnabled nor backgroundFPS.